# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Evaluate the limit $$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^\sqrt{n}}.$$

I have tried many ways but haven't get any appropriate result. 
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Using Stirling's approximation this trivially diverges to infinity.

Comment: You can also use $(\frac n3)^n\le n! \le (\frac n2)^n$ which is easier to handle (and to remember) than Stirling formula and enough to prove most results involving $n!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get a crude lower bound for $n!:$ The function $\ln x$ is strictly increasing for $x>0.$ So for $2\le m$ we have $$\ln m>\int_{m-1}^m\ln x\,dx.$$ So for $2\le n\in \Bbb N$ we have $$\ln(n!)=\sum_{m=1}^n\ln m=\sum_{m=2}^n \ln m \quad \text { (because $\ln 1=0$)}>$$ $$>\sum_{m=2}^n \int_{m-1}^m \ln x\,dx=$$ $$=\int_1^n\ln x\, dx=$$ $$=(-x+x\ln x)|_1^n=(n\ln n)-n+1.$$ Therefore, for $2\le n\in \Bbb N$ we have  $$\ln \left(\frac {n!}{n^{\sqrt n}}\right)=\ln (n!)-\sqrt n\,\ln n>$$ $$>(n\ln n)-n+1-\sqrt n\,\ln n=$$ $$=(n-\sqrt n)(\ln n)-n+1.$$ Now for $n>e^3>4$ we have $n-\sqrt n>n/2$ and $\ln n>3,$ implying $$(n-\sqrt n)(\ln n)-n+1>(n/2)(3)-n+1=(n/2)+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you *don't* know the Stirling approximation. With the large-$n$ approximations $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\approx\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}},\,\ln(n+1)-\ln n\approx\frac1n$,$$\ln\frac{(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}=\sqrt{n+1}\ln(n+1)-\sqrt{n}\ln n\sim\frac{\ln n}{2\sqrt{n}},$$so the given sequence has a common ratio $\sim n^{1-1/(2\sqrt{n})}\sim n$, so diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Here another proof without Stirling approximation.

First we prove by induction the following inequality:

$$
2\left( {\frac{n}
{3}} \right)^n  \leqslant n!\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n \geqslant 1
$$
So

1. For $n=1$ the inequality is true.
2. Assume that it is true for $n=h$ so that
   $$
   2\left( {\frac{h}
   {3}} \right)^h  \leqslant h!
   $$
3. We will prove that
   $$
   2\left( {\frac{h}
   {3}} \right)^{h + 1}  \leqslant \left( {h + 1} \right)!
   $$
   We have
   $$
   \begin{gathered}
     2\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)^{h + 1}  = 2\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)^h  \hfill \\
      \hfill \\
      = 2\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)\left[ {\frac{h}
   {3}\left( {1 + \frac{1}
   {h}} \right)} \right]^h  = 2\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)\left( {\frac{h}
   {3}} \right)^h \left( {1 + \frac{1}
   {h}} \right)^h  \leqslant  \hfill \\
      \hfill \\
      \leqslant 2\left( {\frac{{h + 1}}
   {3}} \right)\left( {\frac{h}
   {3}} \right)^h  \cdot 3 = 2\left( {\frac{h}
   {3}} \right)^h \left( {h + 1} \right) \leqslant h!\left( {h + 1} \right) = (h + 1)! \hfill \\ 
   \end{gathered} 
   $$
   Now we consider the proposed limit. Assume WLOG that $n \geq 16$ then

$$
\frac{{n!}}
{{n^{\sqrt n } }} \geqslant 2\left( {\frac{n}
{3}} \right)^n  \cdot \frac{1}
{{n^{\sqrt n } }} = \frac{{2n^{n - \sqrt n } }}
{{3^n }} \geqslant \frac{{2 \cdot 16^{n - \sqrt n } }}
{{3^n }} \geqslant \frac{{2 \cdot 16^{n - \frac{n}
{2}} }}
{{3^n }} = \frac{{2 \cdot 16^{\frac{n}
{2}} }}
{{3^n }} = \frac{{2 \cdot 4^n }}
{{3^n }} = 2\left( {\frac{4}
{3}} \right)^n 
$$

Since
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{4}
{3}} \right)^n  =  + \infty 
$$
you have that 
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{n!}}
{{n^{\sqrt n } }} =  + \infty 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple lower bound
for $n!$.

$n! 
= \prod_{k=1}^n k
\gt \prod_{k=n/2}^n k
\gt (n/2)^{n/2}
$
so
for any $f$ such that
$f(n)/n \to 0$,,
$\dfrac{n!}{n^{f(n)}}
\gt \dfrac{(n/2)^{n/2}}{n^{f(n)}} 
= \dfrac{n^{n/2-f(n)}}{2^{n/2}} 
= (\dfrac{n^{1/2-f(n)/n}}{2^{1/2}})^n 
\to \infty
$.

This is the case
$f(n) = \sqrt{n}$.

This works for any bound
of the form
$n!
\gt (an)^{bn}
$
with
$a, b > 0$
since

$\dfrac{n!}{n^{f(n)}}
\gt \dfrac{(an)^{bn}}{n^{f(n)}} 
= \dfrac{a^{bn}n^{bn}}{n^{f(n)}} 
= (a^bn^{b-f(n)/n})^n 
\to \infty
$.